# web scraping using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am working on a web scraping project using Puppeteer to extract data from a website that offers Udemy coupons. The goal is to scrape the website, extract information such as course titles, descriptions, images, prices, and categories, and filter the results based on predefined categories stored in an array.

I have implemented a Puppeteer script to scrape the website and extract the desired information. However, I am encountering issues with locating and extracting the category information from each course card on the website. The script successfully retrieves the card elements, but when i add the code to check if the category is included in the categoriesArray it always logging no category element found but the count is logged 16, and when i remove the checking it works normal and log all the categories.

```
const categoriesArray = require('./categories');

(async () => {
  try {
    // Launch the browser and open a new blank page
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Navigate the page to a URL
    await page.goto('https://www.discudemy.com/all');
    console.log('Scraping started');

    // Wait for card elements to be present
    await page.waitForSelector('body > article section.card');

    // Retrieve card elements
    const cardsContainer = await page.$$('body > article section.card');
    console.log(`Number of card elements found: ${cardsContainer.length}`);

    for (const card of cardsContainer) {
      try {
        // Find category element within the card
        const categoryElement = await card.$(
          '.extra.content .right.floated.author a .catSpan'
        );
        if (!categoryElement) {
          console.log('Category element not found within card');
          continue; // Skip processing this card if category element not found
        }

        // Extract category text content
        const category = await categoryElement.evaluate((el) =>
          el.textContent.trim()
        );

        // Check if the category is present in the categoriesArray 
        if (categoriesArray.includes(category)) {
          console.log(category);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error occurred while processing card:', error);
        continue; // Skip processing this card if an error occurs
      }
    }

    // Close the browser
    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Can you provide `categoriesArray`? You should be able to `console.log(category, categoriesArray)` above the condition and see the difference.